# iterate list creation from IO Int, How to?

Tags: list, haskell, io, loops

I am playing with [linkedlist](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=12345) problem in python challenge that require querying a next value (guess it be Int).

I create function for get the next value as follows

```
url = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=" 

getNext :: Int -> IO Int
getNext x = do
    rsp <- simpleHTTP (getRequest $ url ++ show x)
    bdy <- getResponseBody rsp
    let num = last $ splitWhen (==' ') bdy
    return (read num::Int)
```

and it work fine (in ghci)

```
> getNext 12345
44827
> getNext 44827
45439
```

While I suppose to *repeatedly call* getNext until I found the answer, I think I should keep the history like I can do in non-monadic world so I can continue from the last value in case something fail.

```
> let nX x = x + 3
> :t nX
nX :: Num a => a -> a
> take 10 $ iterate nX 1
[1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28]
```

I think it should be a monadic lifted version of iterate and found `iterateM_` from Control.Monad.Loops but it didn't work as I expected. There is nothing shown (I think _ suffix mean discard the result but there is no *iterateM*)

```
> :t iterate
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
> :t iterateM_
iterateM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> m b
```

**Question** is how can I get [Int] as in non-monadic iteration. I think I want a function that return `IO [Int]` to be able to pull-out and filter/process in my code like this

```
main = do
    i <- getAllList
    let answer = last i -- or could be a repeated converged value, don't know yet
    putStrLn (show answer)

getAllList :: IO [Int]
```

Comment: How do you know when the answer is found? Are you looking for a specific value?

Comment: @sabauma I don't know but I think so. This is like a puzzle game. You can start from the first quest [here](http://www.pythonchallenge.com)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want your function to terminate early, rather than give back an
infinite list of results, you will want to use `unfoldrM` rather than
`iterateM`. This can be done with something like the following:

```
url = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=" 


start = 12345
stop  = 10000

shouldStop :: Int -> Bool
shouldStop x = x == stop

getNext :: Int -> IO (Maybe (Int, Int))
getNext prev
    | shouldStop prev = return Nothing
    | otherwise       = do
        rsp <- simpleHTTP (getRequest $ url ++ show prev)
        bdy <- getResponseBody rsp
        let num = read $ last $ splitWhen (==' ') bdy :: Int
        print (prev, num)
        return $ Just (num, num)

getAllList :: IO [Int]
getAllList = unfoldrM getNext start
```

This will allow you to define a stopping criteria so that the loop can
terminate, but you will not receive results back until the termination
criteria has been met.

The `unfoldrM` function can be found in the `monad-loops` package, but the
latest version keeps reusing the original seed rather than the one produced by
the generator function (I believe this has been fixed but not uploaded to
Hackage). This is the version of `unfoldrM` that you would want.

```
-- |See 'Data.List.unfoldr'.  This is a monad-friendly version of that.
unfoldrM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m (Maybe (b,a))) -> a -> m [b]
unfoldrM = unfoldrM'

-- |See 'Data.List.unfoldr'.  This is a monad-friendly version of that, with a
-- twist.  Rather than returning a list, it returns any MonadPlus type of your
-- choice.
unfoldrM' :: (Monad m, MonadPlus f) => (a -> m (Maybe (b,a))) -> a -> m (f b)
unfoldrM' f z = go z
    where go z = do
            x <- f z
            case x of
                Nothing         -> return mzero
                Just (x, z)     -> do
                        xs <- go z
                        return (return x `mplus` xs)
```

This is how you might go about this using `Pipes`, which will allow you to
do the processing as a stream of results without resorting to lazy I/O.

```
import Network.HTTP
import Control.Monad
import Data.List.Split
import Control.Monad
import Control.Proxy

url = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing="

grabber :: (Proxy p) => Int -> () -> Producer p String IO ()
grabber start () = runIdentityP $ loop $ show start where
    loop x = do
        -- Grab the next value
        x' <- lift $ getNext x
        -- Send it down stream
        respond x'
        -- Keep grabbing
        loop x'

-- Just prints the values recieved from up stream
printer :: (Proxy p, Show a) => () -> Consumer p a IO r
printer () = runIdentityP $ forever $ do
    a <- request ()  -- Consume a value
    lift $ putStrLn $ "Received a value: " ++ show a

getNext :: String -> IO String
getNext prev = do
    rsp <- simpleHTTP (getRequest $ url ++ prev)
    bdy <- getResponseBody rsp
    let num  = last $ splitWhen (== ' ') bdy
    return num

main = runProxy $ grabber start >-> printer
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to see if this can be adopted. I have no idea on *terminate condition* for this puzzle. `stop` might don't make any sense. The only information I have is I have to keep requesting with value form last returned. 

I think the ideal solution should be lazy IO that I can see each return value pop up from putStr even if it is infinite list.

Comment: @wizzup Lazy IO is generally considered the wrong thing to do. It is tempting, but opens up a can of worms. I added some code on how to do this with `Pipes` that you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is basically

```
iterateM :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> m [a]
iterateM action a = do
   a' <- action a
   liftM (a':) $ iterateM action a'
```

The problem is that this doesn't work lazily as one might expect: since the monadic bind is strict, you're stuck in an infinite loop, even if you only want to evaluate a finite number of `a`s.

Comment: The monadic bind need not be strict, `iterateM` would work with `Control.Monad.State.Lazy` and a few others. Those are too special for `iterateM` to be generally useful, though.

Comment: Don't know if I get this all correct. Can I conclude that there is no such lazy list generation that mimic `iterate` for IO monad? Just curious, if list is a kind of monad, why not all monad have this characteristic?

Comment: Ah! I do forget that IO is not just a monad but it also not pure. So this make sense on why it is different.

Comment: Actually, `IO` _is_ pure, that's not the problem. Only, it has to be strict.